# Firestore with promises and push

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Thanks to Frank over at Firebase for [helping me with this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003807/firestore-query-with-subcollection). I just had this one issue with pushing the document id under Friends collection. I am not sure what is the best way to push `const friendId` and `const accepted` to `friendsList` array in the code below.

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const friendRef = 
db.collection('users').doc(id).collection('friends');

friendRef.get().then((onSnapshot) => {
  var promises = [];

  onSnapshot.forEach((friend) => {
    const personId = String(friend.data().person_id);
    const friendId = String(friend.id);
    const accepted = friend.data().accepted;

    promises.push(db.collection('users').doc(personId).get());
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
    friendsList = [];
    snapshots.forEach((result) => {
      friendsList.push({
        friendId: friendId,
        accepted: accepted,
        firstName: result.data().name.first,
        lastName: result.data().name.last,
      });
    });
    res.send(friendsList);
  });
}).catch((e) => {
  res.send({
    'error': e
  });
})
```

I tried a few things, but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Where do you define `friendsList` array? In the code part, where you write `friendId: friendId`, variables `friendId` are not defined. They are left in the block of `onSnapshot.forEach`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you push in the `promises` array what you get from the calls `db.collection('users').doc(personId).get()` for each `friend` value. And you never keep values of `personId`, `friendId`, `accepted` for each friend except as local variables.

You should keep them in every array of promises. For this you can return custom Promise like this.

```
promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.collection('users').doc(personId).get()
    .then(docResult => {
        resolve({         
            friendId: friendId,
            accepted: accepted,
            doc: docResult
        });
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        reject(reason);
    });
});
```

and then when you iterate snapshots array:

```
snapshots.forEach((result) => {
    friendsList.push({
        friendId: result.friendId,
        accepted: result.accepted,
        firstName: result.doc.data().name.first,
        lastName: result.doc.data().name.last,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I also just commented in my answer to your original question, there was a typo in my code there stemming from the confusing variable names.

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const friendRef = db.collection('users').doc(id).collection('friends');

friendRef.get().then((friendsSnapshot) => {
  var promises = [];

  friendsSnapshot.forEach((friend) => {
    const friendId = String(friend.data().person_id);    
    promises.push(db.collection('users').doc(friendId).get());
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then((friendDocs) => {
    friendsList = [];
    friendDocs.forEach((friendDoc) => {
      friendsList.push({
        personId: friendDoc.id,
        firstName: friendDoc.data().name.first,
        lastName: friendDoc.data().name.last,
      });
    });
    res.send(friendsList);
  });
}).catch((e) => {
  res.send({
    'error': e
  });
})
```

Since you're looking up the friend's data with `doc(friendId)`, the `friendDoc.id` in the `then()` callback will be the ID of each friend.

In cases like this I **highly** recommend keeping the Cloud Firestore reference documentation handy. For example, in this case I found [`DocumentSnapshot.id`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) to do what is needed.

Comment: Thanks Frank, but I went ahead and accepted the answer from  @TurkhanBadalov because it provided a way for me to also push `const accepted` to friendsList.