# How do I iterate through the results of a firebase get

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to all the users from a firebase doc. I suspect my problem is a limitation with my understanding with javascript though.

I've tried this with and without the async/dispatch pattern with no luck

```
const getUsers = () => {
    database.collection('users').onSnapshot(docs => {
      const users = [];
      docs.forEach(doc => {
        users.push({
          ...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id,
          ref: doc.ref,
        });
      });
      return users;
    });
  };
```

```
let users = getUsers();
  users &&
    users.map(user => {
      console.log('name: ', user.displayName);
    });
```

Ultimately, I'd like to loop through each user

Comment: @Shidersz that won't help because `let u = ` will happen in the future but `return u;` happens in the past.

Comment: @GazihanAlankus yeah, I can see the `async` method now, missed that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore query with subcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003807/firestore-query-with-subcollection)

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @GazihanAlankus, since the query to the Firestore database is an asynchronous operation, you need to return a Promise in your function, by using the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method, as follows:

```
  const getUsers = () => {
    return   //Note the return here
      database
      .collection('users')
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        const users = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          users.push({
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
            ref: doc.ref
          });
        });
        return users;
      });
  };
```

Then you need to call it as follows:

```
  getUsers().then(usersArray => {
    console.log(usersArray);
    usersArray.map(user => {
      console.log('name: ', user.displayName);
    });
  });
```

because the function returns a Promise, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then.

---

You can do the following test and see in which order the `console.log()`s are executed and what the second `console.log()` prints in the console:

```
  getUsers().then(usersArray => {
    console.log(usersArray);
    usersArray.map(user => {
      console.log('name: ', user.name);
    });
  });

  console.log(getUsers());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a non-async function that gets users from Firebase. You're trying to make impossible happen.

Here's what's wrong with your code: the `return users;` is returning from the closure that you give to `onSnapshot`. It's not returning from `getUsers`. There is no `return` in `getUsers`, so it actually returns `undefined`.

The closure you give to `onSnapshot` runs in the future but `getUsers` has to return in the past. There is no way to pass that data in the past when you don't have it. You have to return a promise and deal with it in the calling code. You cannot write a getUsers that directly returns the users instantly.