# Getting {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null} when trying to get data from firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app in react native and trying to get some data from my firestore collection. I created the collection like this:

```js
db.collection("admin-users").add({email: "adminuseremail"})
```

Here the `db` is a `firebase.firestore()` object. I am trying to get the data like this:

```js
const snapshot = db.collection("admin-users").get();
snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
```

But I am geting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. When I try to log snapshot I get `{"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}` in my terminal.

This is how my firebase rules configuration looks like:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

This problem can occur for incorrect promise handling, like not using async/await. How would I use await in my react native app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get()` is an asynchronous operation that returns a `Promise`, so you're displaying the data of that promise rather than of the document in the database.

If you're already in an `async` context, you can use `await` to wait for the promise to complete:

```
const snapshot = await db.collection("admin-users").get();
snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
```

If you can't use `await`, you can always use `then` to accomplish the same:

```
db.collection("admin-users").get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
});
```

Dealing with asynchronous operations like this is very common in modern web development, so I recommend reading up on it with:

- the MDN documentation on [learning Asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)
- [Firestore query with subcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003807/firestore-query-with-subcollection/48010874#48010874)
- [NodeJS, Firestore get field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684796/nodejs-firestore-get-field/52684969#52684969)
- [Why Does Firebase Lose Reference outside the once() Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890)

Answer (score 0):

## Use Async/Await or any other JS operations to handle asynchronous operations

In general, `{"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}` error is due to incorrect Promise handling. For eg, not using async/await.

For your case refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document